@for loop not working properly in nz-dropdown
i am working on a dropdown menu that can have its items passed by input.
using the dropdown menu from ng-zorro here is the code:
  <nz-dropdown-menu #menu="nzDropdownMenu">
    <ul nz-menu>
      @for (item of menu; track $index) {
        <li nz-menu-item (click)="menuItemclicked(item)">
          {{ item }}
        </li>
      }
    </ul>
  </nz-dropdown-menu>

and the @input
@Input() public menu: string[] = []

In this code the menu in my loops is marked with and error:
Type 'NzDropdownMenuComponent' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.
when i rewrite the code with the old ngFor it works...
<li *ngFor="let item of menu; let i = index" nz-menu-item (click)="menuItemclicked(item)">
  {{ item }}
</li>

Any idea what is the issue here?
ps: it compiles

You have a template reference variable with the same name as the @Input that is why it is not using the array but using the template reference variable.
This is happening with the old syntax also, so the naming was the problem.
<a nz-dropdown [nzDropdownMenu]="menuRef">
  Hover me
  <span nz-icon nzType="down"></span>
</a>
<nz-dropdown-menu #menuRef="nzDropdownMenu"> <!--  changed here! -->
  <ul nz-menu>
    @for (item of menu; track $index) {
      <li nz-menu-item (click)="menuItemclicked(item)">
        {{ item }}
      </li>
    }
  </ul>
</nz-dropdown-menu>

and the @input
@Input() public menu: string[] = []

Stackblitz Demo

oh, this it didnt cross my mind... just "bad" naming!
thks very much
